# Enable styles in Design tabs of RTF field

Tags: 2011, rtf

We are using Tridion 2011 SP1. Is there any way to enable styles in Design tabs of RTF field? We have preview tab but editors are finding it as an extra activity to click on preview tab and see the look and feel.

In Tridion 5.3 in design tab as well style were applying. We have 2 paragraphs in RTF field but when we check it in design tab we can't see paragraph formatting rather `<p>` tag is treated as `</br>` tag.

Comment: This is not what i mean.
The editors can not see the difference between a p-tag and a br-tag in the design-tab.
There is no spacing between regel1-p-tag and regel2-p-tag.
In tridion-2009 they can.

Answer (score 4):

The Design tab will show you all styles, provided you have added these in the `FormatAreaStyles.css`, see the [documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_8495FD06A47D4418A41A32D2A714430F) for details ([requires login](http://docportal.sdl.com/sdltridion)).

You basically configure a system wide cascading style sheet for use with your format area fields. In the Schema you can then enable which classe/styles can be applied to text within a format area field. But this will also allow you to set things like the font style and size for the entire format area.

This system wide cascading style sheet is not published to your presentation system, it is only there for the format area, you basically tailor make it to what you have on your published websites. As described in the [documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_8495FD06A47D4418A41A32D2A714430F), you create a `FormatAreaStyles.css` in the `..\Tridion\web\WebUI\Editors\CME\Configuration\` folder of your CMS (make sure to do it for all CMS instances if you have an outscaled environment).

Comment: Also - be aware of the point noted by Bart 'system wide' means that if you have a multi-tenant scenario you need to consider how different users will see/use (mentally filter) the styles that are made available to them. (unless you build some sort of extension to filter - perhaps on naming conventions - styles presented to users depending on publications/sections etc.)